# Open mailto link with another client in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, microsoft-outlook, mailto

I would like to have the option to right-click on a mailto: link in Safari and tell it to open in another mail client. Currently I have Outlook set as my default mail client as that is my work client, but I use Sparrow as my personal email. I would like to be able to click the mailto: links on Craigslist ads and get all the goodness of the pre-filled email fields, but in Sparrow.

There is a very similar question posed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889683/open-link-in-firefox-via-contextual-menu-using-applescript

Unfortunately I don't understand AppleScript well enough to understand the variables involved. If anyone can help explain it to me I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just drag and drop mailto links to Sparrow or Mail.

I tried making a service like this, but it didn't seem to work with mailto URLs:

[image]